# Jquery Menu closer

Tags: jquery

So i am working on this simple script which should hide any object when you have clicked outside of it.

Here is [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9H2DR/) and my simple code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    Click anywhere in this div

    <div style="border:1px solid blue; float:right;">div should still open/close</div>
</div>

<div class="close_me">Close me!</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(".container").click(function(){
    $(".close_me").toggle();
});


helper_close(".close_me", ".container");

//this is simplified example of my function
function helper_close(target, avoid){
    //note that this function will be called once per object
    //so it should be fine to bind new event on document
    $(document).on("click", function(event){

        if( $(event.target).is(avoid) )
            return true;

        $(target).hide();
    });
}
```

​Now as you can see it works, (kind of) the problem is that `close_me` should also appear/disappear when you have clicked anywhere inside of `container`, which as you can see doesn't happen right now.

I know that i could just specify every object i want to "avoid" but what if i have 20 divs inside that container? Well the code would look very ugly... So i need some better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if the clicked element has a parent somewhere up the chain matching the "avoid" selector, if not, hide :

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
    if(! $(event.target).closest(avoid).length ) $(target).hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9H2DR/1/)

Comment: +1, also `if( $(event.target).closest(avoid).length ) return;` if OP wants to keep the same structure.

Comment: Nice, i have tried to achieve same thing with `has` and `parents` but obviously that didn't work, thanks.